# How to create a Bitwise Nand of memory cell 0 and 1, result recorded in memory cell 2

Tags: assembly, binary, nand2tetris

i am trying to create a Nand.asm file to use in a CPUEmulator. Here is my file,

````
 ```
// Bitwise Nand of memory cell 0 and 1, result recorded in memory cell 2.

@0
D = M      // D = a
@2
M = D      // M[2] = a
@1
D = M      // D = b
@2
D = D & M  // D = a & b (bitwise AND)
D = !D     // D = !(a & b) (bitwise NOT of the AND operation, NAND operation)
@2
M = D      // M[2] = !(a & b)



(END)
@END
0; JMP
```
````

But when i try to test the file by making memory cell 0 = 3, and memory cell 1 = 5, it returns -2 into memory cell 2, which I don't think is the bitwise NAND of 3 and 5. I don't completely understand the bitwise NAND but I don't think it's right.

Could anyone help me see what im doing wrong or explain how bitwise NAND works?

Comment: 0011(3) and 0101(5) = 0001(1). not 0001(1) = 1110(-2) in 2's complement. 2 = 0010, reverse bits and add 1 -> 1101 + 1 = 1110 = -2

Comment: It is just the debugger/simulator showing the number as signed, when you probably really want to view that bit pattern as unsigned. 3 nand 5, in 4 binary digits = 1110(binary) = 0xE (hex) = 14(decimal, unsigned) and also = -2 (decimal, signed).